# Display a datatable using jstl

Tags: java, sql, jsp, web-applications, jstl

In my java web application, I have a data table called "sell"

```
sell(id_sell,id_buyer,id_product,date,final_price,shipping_price,sales_tax)
```

I have created a jsp page which display some information about the user, such as the products which won at the auction; these products are described by "sell". In this page I have to use jstl library and my idea is to use 'c:forEach' tag to iterate every row of the table.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Final Price</th>
                <th>Shipping Price</th>
                <th>Salex Tax</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="s" items="${sell}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${s.id_product}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${s.date}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${s.final_price}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${s.shipping_price}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${s.sales_tax}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But this code shows only an empty table. Where am I doing wrong? Do I have to import something?

Comment: Bind that `sell` collection to request/session/page scope.

Comment: My idea is to create a servlet that takes all the data from "sell" and then use session.setAttribute("data",sell). Is it right?

Comment: It's right, you only need to set the data in a scope, so your JSP can access it through the EL expression in the `<c:forEach>` **items** attribute.

Comment: It's time to learn about servlets: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1):

From your servlet, load the needed data from your data source, and add it to a scope. Your JSP will then be able to access it through an EL expression. For example, to add data in the request scope:

```
List<> data = yourDao.list();
request.setAttribute("sell", data);
```

About your comment on your own question, use the session scope wisely. Good practice is to use the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After setting the attribute, do you reccomend to use "forward" or "sendRedirect"?

Comment: forward(). You can take a look at the basic examples in the link BalusC gave you, they're really clear & useful : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info